# How to install SU2 using Cywing

Tags: unix

I am trying to install SU2-CFD code on my computer. I am using Cywing with Windows 10. Installation guide as in the picture below. I have done everyting until ./make command. When I write the ./make command, it says "-bash: ./make: No such file or directory". Could you please help me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For solving a problem, I wrote "make" instead of "./make". Inside of the "make" command, I wrote "./make install-sh"

[image]